# Настройка корпоративной почты на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

На предприятии дали задание:
1. Есть аккаунт anton9009@yandex.ru, через который нужно принимать и отправлять почту.
2. Есть локальные аккаунты user1@corporate.lan и user2@corporate.lan.

Нужно реализовать отправку почты от например user1@corporate.lan на какой-то адрес на test@yandex.ru к примеру и это письмо должно отправиться от anton9009@yandex.ru. И когда test@yandex.ru будет отвечать на anton9009@yandex.ru это письмо должно прийти на user1@corporate.lan
Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: а в чём вопрос-то состоит?

Comment: В том, как это реализовать? Сейчас читаю про Postfix нужен вроде relay у провайдера

Comment: а что именно реализовать-то? не «напрягать весь жёсткий диск»? уберите, пожалуйста, из вопроса то, что к нему не относится.

Comment: Реализовать отправку от локальной почты user1@corporate.lan например на адрес test@yandex.ru, но чтоб письмо к test@yandex.ru пришло не от user1@corporate.lan, а от anton9009@yandex.ru. И когда test@yandex.ru будет отвечать на anton9009@yandex.ru, то письмо должно прийти на user1@corporate.lan

Comment: для забора почты: google://fetchmail+procmail+forward [1](https://fak3r.com/2011/07/07/howto-retrieve-email-with-fetchmail-and-forward-it-on-with-procmail/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19097847/4827341) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: вопрос слишком общий. выглядит как задание для фрилансера. конкретизируйте его, пожалуйста, чтобы можно было **дать ответ**, а не выполнить задание.

Comment: Спасибо, буду дома почитаю, попробую еще...

Comment: У яндекса разве нет услуги корпоративной почты или она дорого стоит? Получишь при этом нормальные адреса сколько нужно вместо одного левого. И наверняка должен быть способ перекачивать ящики на свою бубунту. Двадцать лет назад ни хрена не было, а теперь-то зачем извращаться до такой степени? https://pdd.yandex.ru/domains_add/#tab=2

Comment: Официальная почта должна быть на внешке государственная, поэтому такое придумали

Answer (score 1):

вопрос на самом деле состоит из нескольких очень обширных вопросов, потому привожу лишь краткое и поверхностное описание необходимых глобальных шагов.

ниже буду испльзовать сокращения из статьи [Email agent (infrastructure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure)), в ней по ссылкам можно найти примеры реализаций тех или иных агентов.

1. для того, чтобы с помощью [*mua*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) можно было прочитать сообщения, поступившие пользователю `user1@corporate.lan`, нужна связь с настроенным *maa* (статьи про *mail access agent* в википедии нет, потому описания и примеры реализаций см. в статьях про протоколы, используемые для связи с *maa*: [imap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) и [pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol))
2. для того, чтобы с помощью *mua* можно было отправить сообщение пользователю `user1@corporate.lan`, нужна связь с настроенным [*mta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) (по протоколу [*smtp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol))
3. домен `corporate.lan` в настройках *mta* должен быть описан как *localdomain*, чтобы сообщения складывались локально, туда, где их сможет прочитать *maa*
4. чтобы сообщения, адресованные пользователям не из локального(ых) домена(ов), отправлялись яндексовскому (или любому другому) серверу, надо в настройках *mta* прописать этот сервер как [*smarthost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host) с авторизацией (или, если сервер позволяет, без таковой), а обратный (локальный) адрес должен быть заменён на глобально доступный (в вашем случае — `anton9009@yandex.ru`)
5. сообщения, поступившие пользователю `anton9009@yandex.ru`, надо будет забирать с яндексовских *maa* при помощи [*mra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_retrieval_agent), и перенаправлять пользователю `user1@corporate.lan`. часто для этих двух задач используют связку из *fetchmail+procmail* ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19097847/4827341))

---

соображения по поводу разных локальных отправителей и ответов на их сообщения:

т.к. при отправке *smarthost*-у (т.е., во внешний мир) обратный (несуществующий для внешнего мира) адрес должен быть заменён на работоспособный (в вашем случае — на `anton9009@yandex.ru`), ответные сообщения могут быть переадросованы лишь какому-то одному локальному пользователю.